# How to add touch event for drawRect in Android

Tags: java, android

I have created the rectangle using drawRect() in `Canvas` in onDraw() method

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
{   

    canvas.drawRect(20, 30, 10, 10, Color.RED);

}
```

How to get the event for this rectangle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your View's `onTouchEvent` method, which you should override to achieve this, you'll get a `MotionEvent`, then you can access the position where your touch event occurs like `event.getX()` and `event.getY()`.Then , check if your `Rect.contains(event.getX(),event.getY())`;

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get an event for something you draw like that, unless you manually check if a click on the main canvas falls within the bounds of the rectangle.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Eric, Then how can I add click or Listener for main canvas